# What happens with strings in russian when I POST form

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, encode

Have an edit form in my web application, when using English language everything ok, but when I've tried create new test record in Russian I've got something like this, after submit form: `&#1053;&#1072; &#1088;&#1091;&#1089;&#1089;&#1082;&#1086;&#1084; &#1090;&#1077;&#1089;&#1090` instead of `"На русском языке"` ...
My html form:

```html
 <form th:action="@{'/save/' + ${recipe.id}}" method="post" th:object="${recipe}">
                    <input type="hidden" id="recipeIdInput" th:field="${recipe.id}" th:value="${recipe.id}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" id="recipeFavorite" th:field="${recipeFavorite}" th:value="${recipeFavorite}"/>

                    <div th:each="favUser, stat : ${recipe.favoriteUsers}" hidden="hidden">
                        <input hidden="hidden" th:id="@{'favUser' + ${stat.index}}" th:value="${favUser.username}"/>
                    </div>

                    <p hidden="hidden" id="recipeId" th:text="${recipe.id}"/>
                    <p hidden="hidden" id="recipeUserName" th:text="${recipe.user.username}"/>

                    <div class="grid-100 row controls">
                        <div class="grid-50">
                            <h2> Recipe Editor </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-50">
                            <div class="flush-right">
                                <button type="submit">Save Recipe</button>
                                <a href="/"><button type="button" class="secondary">Cancel</button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="clear"></div>

                    <div class="grid-100 row">
                        <div class="grid-20">
                            <p class="label-spacing">
                                <label> Name </label>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-40">
                            <p>
                                <input id="recipeName" type="text" th:placeholder="${recipe.name}" th:field="${recipe.name}"/>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-40">
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/save/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveRecipe(@ModelAttribute @Valid Recipe recipe, BindingResult result, @PathVariable Long id, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

    recipe.setUser(getLoggedUser());
    if (recipe.getCategory() != null)
        recipe.setCategory(categoryService.findById(recipe.getCategory().getId()));
    recipe.setFavoriteUsers(recipeService.findById(recipe.getId()).getFavoriteUsers());
    recipe.setPhoto(recipeService.findById(recipe.getId()).getPhoto());

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        for (ObjectError o : result.getAllErrors())
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("flash",new FlashMessage(o.toString(), FlashMessage.Status.FAILURE));
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("recipe", recipe);
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("recipeFavorite", recipe.isFavorite(getLoggedUser()));
        return "redirect:/edit/"+id;
    }

    recipeService.save(recipe);
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("flash", new FlashMessage("Recipe saved.", FlashMessage.Status.SUCCESS));
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

So, what happens with those nice russian letters and how decode this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its the encoding issue. You need to use `CharacterEncodingFilter` to set UTF-8 encoding here.

**Specify below filter in web.xml**

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

**Purpose of this filter :-**
Filter that allows one to specify a character encoding for
 requests. This is useful because current browsers typically do not set a
character encoding even if specified in the HTML page or form.